# WSUS downloading driver updates every night

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsus

I have a WSUS server running on Windows Server 2012. We use it because of limited bandwidth available here

Every night at 3 AM it downloads 2+ GB of updates, even though a "synchronise now" event during the day shows nothing new required

The synchronisation report show mostly Windows Drivers, like this:

```
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. driver update for AMD
Radeon HD 7500G
Drivers 7/28/2015 3:06 AM
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. driver update for AMD
Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series
Drivers 7/28/2015 3:06 AM
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. driver update for AMD
Radeon HD 7540D
Drivers 7/28/2015 3:06 AM
```

Any idea to why this is happening every night? Surely there can't be 2+ GB of new drivers released every day?

I only have these products selected in "products and classifications":

- Office 2013
- SQL 2014
- Skype
- Silverlight
- Windows 8.1
- Windows 10
- Windows Defender
- Windows Server 2012

The server is a VM, it's running stable, and has RAM and disk to spare

Comment: Well, you told us the "products", but not the "classifications". Please provide these too. I remember WSUS sometimes downloading drivers via the classification "tools" as well.

Comment: @Lenniey Classifications is on default, which is everything ticked? I assume it would download among other things the "drivers" for the products I have selected. But every night another 2GB+ of updated drivers?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question, I thought you didn't want WSUS to download any drivers at all.

Comment: @Lenniey defiantly want everything required for products selected, so assume that would included drivers?

Comment: I definitely don't want drivers to be downloaded for my servers, if I want to upgrade them at all, I'll do it myself. I got everything checked but drivers, this will download all patches, update rollups, etc.. Drivers I care for myself. (And I really don't know if MS fixed their "one-to-one" WSUS driver download problem: [Old link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sus/archive/2008/08/20/a-large-number-of-driver-updates-showing-up-in-wsus.aspx) )

Answer (score 1):

Enought free space on the partition where updates are downloaded ?

IMHO it's a nonsense to download all from WSUS.

Why you don't mark the checkbox "Download update files to this server only when updates are approved" in Options / Update Files and Languages.

You will receive the information about the update and after the approve it will be downloaded. Obviously you should only approve the updates some of your computers in your network needs. You can see if some of your computers need that update adding the column "required count" on the pane with the updates.